# Implementing image slider with thumbs using ngx-swiper-wrapper

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement ngx-swiper-wrapper to build an image slider with thumbs similar to this:

https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html

Has anyone managed to do this? I can't see any good documentation on how to build all swiper sliders with this wrapper. Also, is the FlexLayoutModule that is used in the demo for ngx-swiper-wrapper a must or can it be implemented without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an demo and example for you.

https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gallery

**npm install ngx-gallery --save**

```
// app.module.ts
import { NgxGalleryModule } from 'ngx-gallery';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        NgxGalleryModule
        ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }

<ngx-gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery>
```

I have just added sample docs please visit that npm package and install.

Comment: Even if it's not the same plugin I was mentioning this suggested plugin was very easy to use and works perfectly. I changed to using it instead. Many thanks!

Comment: can we use this npm for video also ?

Answer (score 2):

We have working demo in native JS.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-31-thumbs-gallery-with-loop-mode?file=index.html

---

For Angular you only should add thumbs to *SwiperConfigInterface* like this:

```
galleryTopConfig: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    thumbs: {
      swiper: Object.assign(this.galleryThumbsConfig, {el: '.gallery-thumbs'})
    }
  };
```

and apply config

```
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top" [swiper]="galleryTopConfig">
```

For *.gallery-thumbs* you should apply config by the same way.

(from docs https://swiperjs.com/api/#thumbs)